# BufferedWriter Clears Text File When Writing

Tags: java, bufferedwriter

I am having an odd problem with my BufferedWriter. It seems that every time I write something to a text file using it, it clears the text file and writes that one line. I need it to add lines, not start fresh with each print. Here's my code:

```
public void write(String str) {
    try {
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(savefile));
        out.write(str);
        out.newLine();
        out.flush();
    }
    catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
}
```

There are no exceptions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `FileWriter` constructor that uses append mode:

```
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(savefile, true));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(savefile, true));
```

The second argument passed to the `FileWriter` constructor specifies if it should append.

Here's a link to the [documentation for `new FileWriter(File, boolean)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter%28java.io.File,%20boolean%29).